# 'Error in gregexpr' when render R Markdown to HTML

Tags: r, yaml, r-markdown, knitr

My RStudio(version 1.1.414) is not able to render a R Markdown file into HTML. I have a very simple R Markdown file called `testHTML.Rmd`:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output:
html_document: default  
---    
## R Markdown
This is a test!
```

In my main R code, I am calling the render() statement as `render('testHTML.Rmd')`. I got the following error message related to regexp:

> Error in gregexpr("(?)`r[ #]([^`]+)\\s*`", "---\ntitle:
>   \"Untitled\"\noutput:\n html_document: default\n \n---\n", : invalid
>   regular expression '(?<!(^| ))`r[ #]([^`]+)\s*`', reason 'Invalid
>   regexp'

Has anyone seen this error before when knit an R Markdown file? What is the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me updating all installed packages worked after I got the same error message.

The problem occured after updating RStudio to 1.1.463 and R to 3.5.2. I was asked to update knitr, rmarkdown and yaml ( I think, at least three packages were mentioned ).  After updating yaml the error occured.

Updating all existing packages made the error disappear again. Hope this helps.